# Laravel count results on specific date and column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In my database I am having the following records:

```
id    code   product_amount         created_at
 1    ORD-1      250          2016-04-04 05:15:05 PM
 2    ORD-1      150          2016-04-04 05:15:05 PM
 3    ORD-2      450          2016-04-05 11:18:17 PM
 4    ORD-3      250          2016-04-06 04:30:25 PM
 5    ORD-3      300          2016-04-06 04:30:25 PM
 6    ORD-3      750          2016-04-06 04:30:26 PM
 7    ORD-4      650          2016-04-06 08:30:26 PM
 7    ORD-4      150          2016-04-06 08:30:27 PM
```

Now what I want is I want to count the orders that are placed on each day, So the output should be:

```
count  date
  1    2016-04-04 // For ORD-1
  1    2016-04-05 // For ORD-2
  2    2016-04-06 // For ORD-3 and ORD-4
```

The code that I tried so far:

```
$ordersList = Order::latest();

$ordersListDate = $ordersList->selectRaw('date(created_at) as date')
                  ->groupBy('date')->get()
                  ->lists('date')->toArray();

$ordersListCount = $ordersList->select([
    DB::raw('DATE(created_at) AS date'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(code) AS count')
])->groupBy('date')->get()->lists('count')->toArray();
```

The above controller gives when I do `dd($ordersListCount)`:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "1"
  2 => "5"
]
```

I am scratching my head since long time and couldn't get this done. I know there must be silly thing that I must have missed or not considering, but I am still at the learning stage.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @splash58 tried that as well, it didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want such query

```
select count(distinct code) count, date(created_at) as `date`
    from orders
  group by date
```

but I can't write it on your laravel language :(

sqlfiddle has answered just now. its a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a289/1)

Comment: Your solution has worked for me.. Thank you.. You made my day... :)

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a column date in (YYYY-MM-DD format) remember not DATETIME format in your table. Then you can easily group it by date and count the orders with the following query:

```
Order::select(array('date', DB::raw('COUNT(code) AS count')))->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but I want to do it on `created_at` field only and I don't want to create any new column with `DATETIME` column type.

Comment: im not sure you can do that with created_at column unless you scrap the time part from the created_at

Comment: That is what this piece of code does: `DB::raw('DATE(created_at) AS date')` . I have scrapped the time part and then I want to display the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order::select(array(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) AS date')), DB::raw('COUNT(code) AS count')))->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following query will solve your issue. I have tested it ...

```
$ordersListCount = $ordersList->select([
    DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT code) as count'),
    DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as date')
])->groupBy('date')->get()->toArray();
```